# how to include user defined package when do maven compile

Tags: maven, compilation

Followed is my project structure.

```
com.company.univ.scheduler.api
--src
----com
-----company
-------univ
--------scheduler
----------api
------------annotation
           ---Column.java
           ---Id.java
           ---pom.xml
-------------model
           ----App.java
           ----job.java
           ----Task.java
           ----pom.xml
-------------service
           ----LockService.java
           ----ResultService.java
           ----TaskService.java
           ----pom.xml
```

Under model folder,the App.java will have to import annotation's java file.
Like

```
import com.company.univ.scheduler.api.Column;
import com.company.univ.scheduler.api.Id;
```

Likewise,all files distributed under various folder would be related.How would maven pom.xml handle this issue?

P.S When do maven compile,there always show error message like"can not find symbol;"
"method can not be override"..... I have checked those java files to the target line but no that obvious errors likely to happen,As our project was build in Ant before and all fine.

The maven compile info:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO]-------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] ..\com.company.univ.scheduler.api\src\com\company\univ\scheduler\api\model\Task.java:[7,50] package com.company.univ.scheduler.api doesnt exist
[ERROR] ..\com.company.univ.scheduler.api\src\com\company\univ\scheduler\api\model\Task.java:[8,50] package com.company.univ.scheduler.api doesnt exist [ERROR] ..\com.company.univ.scheduler.api\src\com\company\univ\scheduler\api\model\Task.java:[26,2] can not find symbol 
symbol:class Column
location:class com.company.univ.scheduler.api.model.task
[ERROR] ..\com.company.univ.scheduler.api\src\com\company\univ\scheduler\api\model\Task.java:[22,2] can not find symbol 
symbol:class Id
location:class com.company.univ.scheduler.api.model.task
```

Comment: "There is a way to make the user defined package a jar file then add the dependency ???" - can you please redit it and make your question clear? - Thank

Answer (score 0):

Java source should be in `src/main/java`, which is the root of your package hierarchy.

I would *strongly* urge you to use the [standard Maven directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Why are there pom files in each of your packages?

Comment: Because its a Multi-module project and we want use maven based on current project structure.Is it possible?

Comment: @PeterTian I suppose, although I don't recall how. Good luck.